# Scala - How to parse many-one relationships?

Tags: scala, parsing, playframework

### Architecture

I have two tables, say `teams` and `players`. Where each row in the players table has a `team_id` foreign key that references the `teams` table.

The result that I want is a JSON array where each element is a team. And that team has a `players_info` key that aggregates some information about players and then has an array of all the players. Basically, I want it to  look like following

```
[
{
    "id": "Arsenal FC",
    "city": "London",
    "stadium_capacity": 60000,
    ....
    "players_info": {
        "count": 34,
        "average_price": 34,
        "players": [
            {
                "name": "Ozil",
                "price": 50,
                ....
            },
            {
                "name": "Wilshere",
                "price": 40,
                ....
            },
            .....   
        ]
},
{
    "id": "Chelsea FC",
    "city": "London",
    "stadium_capacity": 40000,
    ....
    "players_info": {
        "count": 39,
        "average_price": 54,
        "players": [
            {
                "name": "Hazard",
                "price": 60,
                ....
            },
            {
                "name": "Kante",
                "price": 45,
                ....
            },
            .....   
        ]
},
.....
 ]
```

### Problem

This is what I have so far

```
case class Team(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    ....
    players_info: JsValue
)

object Team {
    val parse = {

        ------- What do I do here? -------

        get[Int]("id") ~
        get[String]("name") ~
        .....
        get[String]("player_name") ~
        get[String]("player_price") map {
            case id ~ name ~ player_name ~ player_price ~ ... => Team(id, name, ???)
        }

    }
}

val teams = DB.withConnection {
  implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM teams JOIN players ON players.team_id = teams.id").as(Team.parse *)
}
val response = Json.toJson(teams)
```

I'd like some help on the following

1. How do I construct the `player_info` JsValue in the parser such that can calculate things like `average_price` using my application code and then initialize my `Team` class after everything is ready?
2. I'm not sure if my overall architecture of handling this problem is right. Can I get some thoughts about that as well?
3. I feel like I'm missing some overall context after the concept of parsing and constructing JSON. I know rails where its pretty easy to do such things but I'm lost on how to do the same in Scala. Can you point me to some relevant resources/tutorials where I can educate myself?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create case classes, that would serve as API representation of JSON I will serve.

```
case class ApiTeam(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    ....
    players_info: ApiPlayersInfo
)

case class ApiPlayersInfo(
    ...
)
```

Then I would use Play JSON to [generate decoders/encoders with macros](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated).

```
import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val playersInfoFormat = Json.format[ApiPlayersInfo]
implicit val teamFormar = Json.format[ApiTeam]
```

So I would not parse it manually, but instead just let the Play JSON handle it for me. Then I would just import generated implicits and

```
val teamJson = Json.toJson(apiTeam)
```

As for the content of Team and PlayersInfo, since I would just build normal objects I could use all tools Scala has. So, you can basically calculate things by querying the database, use the results to build Team object and then transform it to JSON.

```
case class Team(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    ....
)

case class PlayersInfo(...)
```

By splitting the tasks into such smaller chunks it will be easier to understand and maintain.

```
for {
  team <- DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM teams JOIN players ON players.team_id = teams.id").as(Team)
  }
  playersInfo <- DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("...").as(PlayersInfo)
  }
} yield {
  val apiTeam = ApiTeam(...)
  Json.toJson(apiTeam)
}
```

Your problem here is that Rails teached you the bad practice of uniform representation: the same class for JSON, read model, write model and database row. It only work when you are write most basic CRUD, and even then it breaks when you have an issue of creating new entity (vide: a lot of problems with: how do I handle missing ID during row creation?). Here you have 2 tables in a database, but want to represent them as a one JSON of aggregated results. Minimal case for keeping it simple is Team model, Player model and a separate model for the aggregated result.

The sooner you start using different representations for different things, the sooner you make it maintainable and flexible.